# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar collapsed only on Phone Mode (No Tablet Mode)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive bootstrap menu, but I don`t want to collaspe it in tablet mode. I try to dysplay the same Menu in desktop and tablet mode.
the menu is collapsed at 940px or less, I want to do it at 768px or less.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

The code:

```
div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- I want to display this code only in Phone mode-->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

      <!-- This  part is hidden (collapsed) at 940px or less
           But I want to collapse it at 768px or less!!!!
      -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
           <!-- menu items -->
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look up "Responsive utility classes" on the [Twitter Bootstrap scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) page

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do it would be to recompile using [LESS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/extend.html) and change the @navbarCollapseWidth variable from 979px to 768px. If you don't want to use LESS you can use the Customize page on the Bootstrap site to change that variable: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to bootstrap-responsive.css file.
2. Go to line number 952.
3. Change the max-width from 979px to 768px.

Comment: Not all tablets hav a logical width of 768px in portrait mode. Please consider this. Apple sticks to 768px, Samsung to 800px.