# Changing width at which Bootstrap menu collapses?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, media-queries

I am running a html template that uses the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Like on the bootstrap site/examples, the main nav bar at the top converts to a mobile optimised one, when the browser width falls below iPad landscape width (I believe its around 980px)

I only have a few menu items, and I would ideally like to keep the full menu, until the browser width falls below iPad portrait width.

Any tips on what I should be looking to change? I've tried adjusting some of the media queries, but i've not had much luck.

Hoping someone will know a bit more accurately about where to start!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be with a custom Bootstrap build. See this question: [Bootstrap Responsive Navbar collapsed only on Phone Mode (No Tablet Mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585535/bootstrap-responsive-navbar-collapsed-only-on-phone-mode-no-tablet-mode)